# How can I continue my step?

Tags: inequality

Like my all before questions, I found it in the same book!:)

Here is the problem:

Let: $x,y,z>0$ and $xyz=1$. Prove that: $\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+x^7+y^7}+\frac{y^2z^2}{y^2z^2+y^7+z^7}+\frac{z^2x^2}{z^2x^2+z^7+x^7}\leq 1$

My idea is use Vasc inequality but change a little bit:

I change: $\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+x^7+y^7}\leq \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+2x^{\frac{7}{2}}y^{\frac{7}{2}}}=\frac{t^2}{t^2+2t^{\frac{7}{2}}}$

Now I want to find a good $k$ that: $\frac{t^2}{t^2+2t^{\frac{7}{2}}}\leq \frac{t^k}{2(t^{2k}+t^k+1)}(*)$

It is written as: $2t^{\frac{7}{2}+k}+2t^{\frac{7}{2}}-t^{2+k}-t^2-2t^{2k+2}\geq 0$

I put: $f(t)=2t^{\frac{7}{2}+k}+2t^{\frac{7}{2}}-t^{2+k}-t^2-2t^{2k+2}$

So I found: $f'(t)=2(\frac{7}{2}+k)t^{\frac{5}{2}+k}+7t^{\frac{5}{2}}-(2+k)t^{k+1}-2t-2(2k+2)t^{2k+1}$

Let: $f'(1)=0$ then found $k=2$

Now $(*)$ is written as: $2t^6 +t^4+t^2 \geq 2t^5.t^{\frac{1}{2}}+2t^3.t^{\frac{1}{2}}$ which is not correct!

Can anybody fix my progress or make a new hand solution! Thank you a lots!

Answer (score 1):

Using $x^7 + y^7 \ge x^4 y^3 + x^3 y^4$, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+x^7+y^7}
&\le \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+x^4y^3 + x^3y^4}\\
&= \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{1}{1+x^2y + xy^2}\\
&= \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{xyz}{xyz+x^2y + xy^2}\\
&= \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{xyz}{xy(x + y + z)}\\
&= \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{z}{x + y + z}\\
&= 1.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Comment: I can't think about the first inequality! I first thought using $x^7 + y^7 >=  x^2y^2(x^5+y^5)$ :)! Thank you!

Comment: @LụcTrườngPhát You are welcome.

Comment: @Lục Trường Phát  $x^7+y^7\geq x^2y^2(x^5+y^5)$ is also works.

Comment: I will try it again

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible!

After your step we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{1+2a}\leq1,$$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positives such that $abc=1$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a+1)(2b+1)\leq\prod_{cyc}(2a+1)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(4ab+4a+1)\leq\sum_{cyc}(3+4ab+2a)$$ or
$$a+b+c\leq3,$$ which is wrong because by AM-GM
$$a+b+c\geq3\sqrt[3]{abc}=3.$$
Id est, your attempt to get a "good $k$" can't help and you can't continue  your step.

Comment: thank you! I realized where i wrong

Comment: @Lục Trường Phát I don't think so. I added something. See now.

Comment: I read this:http://toanhocsocap.blogspot.com/2016/10/bat-ang-thuc-vasc-va-ung-dung.html and want to try can it help

Comment: @Lục Trường Phát I know these inequalities. But it can't help because after your first step we obtain a wrong inequality. It's impossible to continue after your first step.